# Move elements up down onload in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 elements like this

```
<div class="div1">Slider</div>
<div class="div2">User Profile</div>
```

i want this elements structure onload like this(using : jquery, javascript, css)

```
<div class="div2">User Profile</div>
<div class="div1">Slider</div>
```

Comment: so, what you tried?

Comment: i have tried with css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `insertBefore` with `prev` option.

```js
$('.div2').insertBefore($('.div2').prev('.div1'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">Slider</div>
<div class="div2">User Profile</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `insertAfter`

```js
$(".div1").insertAfter($(".div2"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">Slider</div>
<div class="div2">User Profile</div>
```

or before

```js
$(".div2").insertBefore($(".div1"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">Slider</div>
<div class="div2">User Profile</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.before()` or `.after()`:

```
$("#div1").after($("#div2"));
```

OR:

```
$("#div2").before($("#div1"));
```

This method puts the first element before/after the second element, as long as they are adjacent siblings.